# how to generate excel vba code in selenium ide

Tags: excel, selenium-ide, vba

I am using Selenium IDE 2.9.1  (a Firefox plugin) to get web element. I am unable to see VBA code when I go to options > format. Does anybody know how to get or set VBA source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the info from the [documentation](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/09_selenium_ide.jsp#format). This seems to imply format VBA is not a supported feature.

> Format
>
> Format, under the Options menu, allows you to select a language
>   for saving and displaying the test case. The default is HTML.
>
> If you will be using Selenium-RC to run your test cases, this feature
>   is used to translate your test case into a programming language.
>   Select the language, e.g. Java, PHP, you will be using with
>   Selenium-RC for developing your test programs. Then simply save the
>   test case using File=>Export Test Case As. Your test case will be
>   translated into a series of functions in the language you choose.
>   Essentially, program code supporting your test is generated for you by
>   Selenium-IDE.
>
> Also, note that if the generated code does not suit your needs, you
>   can alter it by editing a configuration file which defines the
>   generation process. Each supported language has configuration settings
>   which are editable. This is under the Options=>Options=>Formats tab.
>
> Note
>
> At the time of this writing, this feature is not yet supported by the
>   Selenium developers. However the author has altered the C# format in a
>   limited manner and it has worked well.